# ecomdev phpunit fixture for website specific configuration

Tags: magento, phpunit, tdd, ecomdev-phpunit

I'm trying to understand PHPUNIT + MAGENTO and I found this extension https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit which seems to be great tool.

I want have a fixture which set shipping method 'Freeshipping' per website. I found a solution for default configuration

```
config:
    default/carriers/freeshipping/active: 1
    default/carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal: 150
    default/carriers/freeshipping/name: Free
    ...
```

It works fine. But let's have a website ID = 2 then what do I need to add into fixture's yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would use:

```
config:
  websites/{website_code}/carriers/freeshipping/active: 1
```

However, the config fixtures seem to have unwanted side effects like removing other config nodes.. So as inelegant as it is, I use:

```
public function setUp() {
    Mage::app()->getStore(0)
        ->setConfig('carriers/freeshipping/active', 1);
    // OR
    Mage::getConfig()->setNode('websites/{$code}/carriers/freeshipping/active' 1);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I've been having huge issues with config nodes going missing (Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): Node no longer exists) when using fixtures for config. 

I couldn't find any reference to anyone else having similar issues so was wracking my brain trying to find out what I'd done wrong.

I might create a convenience method for setting up all the config I want in tests to make it a bit more elegant.